# Vuejs v-on eventos | llamar a un metodo al presionar una tecla

Tags: vuejs, keypressevent

Quiero llamar a un método (en mi caso el que abre el modal) al presionar la tecla "f4" (u otra) ¿Cómo se haría eso? ya que según lo que  leí y entendí de la documentación el @kayup.laTecla="miMetodo" solo funciona dentro de un input.

Gracias por la Ayuda

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], para mantener la pregunta abierta y que esta sea clara y fàcil de apoyar recomiendo edites y muestres lo que llevas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con esta función

```js
  function openWithF4(callback) {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 115) {
        callback();
      }
    });
  }
  function demo() {
    alert('Hola mundo');
  }
  openWithF4(demo);
```

Solo dale en ejecutar y después presiona `F4`

Answer (score 1):

> Según lo que leí y entendí de la documentación el @keyup.laTecla="miMetodo" solo funciona dentro de un input.

Funciona sobre cualquier elemento, pero para que funcione, el elemento tiene que ser capaz de recibir foco. Para ello existe la propiedad [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/tabindex).

Hay de tener en cuenta que el elemento que escucha los eventos de teclado debe de tener foco, por lo que en el ejemplo que te pongo, este elemento ocupa el tamaño completo del viewport, para que sea fácilmente accesible.

Al añadir el `tabindex` por defecto se le añade un outline (Puede depender del navegador que uses) que también he eliminado con CSS.

Ejemplo:

```js
// Para poder hacer @keyup.f4="doSomething" ya que no existe en Vue este alias
// https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Codes
Vue.config.keyCodes.f4 = 115;

Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '<div tabindex="-1" @keyup.f4="doSomething" class="container">{{text}}</div>',
  data() {
    return  {
      text: 'Apreta F4 para abrir modal'
    };
  }, 
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      // Lógica para abrir el modal
      alert('show modal');
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  outline: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <modal></modal>
</div>
```

---

Otra opción es usar esta librería ([VueGlobalEvents](https://github.com/shentao/vue-global-events)) que expone un componente, de forma que los eventos que escucha los delega en window. De esta forma nos ahorramos tener que crear el evento `window.addEventListener` y eliminarlo cuando el componente se elimina `window.removeEventListener`.

Ejemplo:

```js
// Para poder hacer @keyup.f4="doSomething" ya que no existe en Vue este alias
// https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Codes
Vue.config.keyCodes.f4 = 115;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    GlobalEvents: window.VueGlobalEvents
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      // Lógica para abrir el modal
      alert('show modal');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-global-events@1.1.2/dist/vue-global-events.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">Apreta F4 para abrir modal</div>
  <global-events @keyup.f4="doSomething" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '<div>test modal</div>',
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      console.log(e.key);
      if (e.key == 'F4') {
       alert("funciona!");
       this.showModal = !this.showModal;
      }
    });
  },
  data: {
    showModal: true
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <modal v-show="showModal"></modal>
</div>
```

Documentación de los keycodes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Ejemplo extraído de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50395988/3613462